# Wordpress plugin localization- Can't display the translations

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, internationalization, translation

I am trying to add translation to my WordPress plugin using `.po` files, but I can't display the translation.

My `.po` and `.mo` files are named as follows:

```
  plugin-name-fr_FR.mo  
  plugin-name-fr_FR.po
```

and are located in the `./languages/`  folder.

In my code, I load the translations like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_translation');

function load_translation() {

    load_plugin_textdomain( 'plugin-name', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__ )) . '/languages/' );

}
```

I have also tried using:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_translation' );
```

but it didn't work either.

The header of my plugin contains :

```
* Text Domain: plugin-name
* Domain Path: /languages
```

When I check the response value of the `load_plugin_textdomain()` function, it returns `true` so the files are being found, but the translations are not displayed.

For displaying my content, I use :

```
 <?= __( 'My text' ); ?>
```

I don't know what to do, can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the custom textdomain, provided that your pot files are correct as well.

```
<?= __( 'My text' , 'plugin-name'); ?>
```